# Write online/offline state to log file

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ping

I'm looking for a way to log the online/offline state of a Linux host to a log file locally.

I tried to use `ping` for this but it didn't log timeouts/dropped packages it only shows successful transmissions:
`ping -D 8.8.8.8 | awk 'NR>1 { printf strftime("%c", $0) "%s",$2; }' RS=[ FS=]`

```
Mi 14 Okt 2015 13:03:06 CEST 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=155 ttl=55 time=18.4 ms
Mi 14 Okt 2015 13:03:07 CEST 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=156 ttl=55 time=18.6 ms
Mi 14 Okt 2015 13:03:08 CEST 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=157 ttl=55 time=18.4 ms
Mi 14 Okt 2015 13:05:19 CEST 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=244 ttl=55 time=18.4 ms
Mi 14 Okt 2015 13:05:20 CEST 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=245 ttl=55 time=18.4 ms
```

So I have to look at the request numbers carefully to detect offline states.

Did anyone know a better way to do it or can name a tool for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are already a lot of tools available that do that, like Munin, Nagios, etc. I don't see why re-creating the wheel, but if you want a shell solution, here it goes:

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="/var/log/up-or-down.log";
ip_address_for_testing="192.168.1.10";

while [[ true ]]; do
    ping -c 5 $ip_address_for_testing;
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "IP status for ${ip_address_for_testing}: UP" >> $logfile;
    else
        echo "IP status for ${ip_address_for_testing}: DOWN" >> $logfile;
    fi;
    sleep 5;
done;
```

The above example will send 5 ECHO REQUESTS to the host defined in $ip_address_for_testing and if all goes well, it'll write in $logfile if it is up or down. Save it to a file, give it execution permissions with chmod and call it through /etc/rc.local or /etc/rcS.d (it you choose the second option, you're gonna have to save it in /etc/init.d and create a symlink to it) if you want to start it on boot time.

Cya!